# Load theme.css after Richfaces ECSS files

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

Anyway to load my custom css after Richfaces's ECSS files?

By putting the `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="theme.css"/>` after the body tag, my theme.css is loaded after all the Richfaces's CSS files, but not the ECSS files (eg. inputNumberSpinner.ecss) as looks like those were loaded dynamically depends on if my page uses those control.

using JSF 2, Richfaces 4

Comment: Even putting it inside h:body should be enough for the resources to be rendered last. Are you using MyFaces or Mojarra?

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.29-04

using the inspector on Firefox, I do see my theme.css loaded and used, but then the inputNumberSpinner.ecss is on top of it and override the settings.

the theme.css is loaded on a template's body, and there are few layer of includes to the richfaces inputNumberSpinner control.

Comment: Even with a template the resource should be linked last, that said styles being overwritten doesn't depend just on the order, and you can always use `!important`.